# UISearchbar (tableHeaderView) issue when scrolling the uitableview on ios7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have searchDisplayController,which is table headerView of my tableView.My tableview scrolling works smooth and perfect and tableview consist of 3 rows.My issue is my tableView scrolls to top,then bounce back at that time my tableViewHeader(UIsearchbar) cannot seen it goes to behind the navigation bar.Then scroll to down i can see my tableViewHeader(UISearch bar). When first time view loading the contentOffset on my console is {0,0},then scroll to top and bounce back at that time my contentOffset last value on my console is {0,44}.How to solve this issue?Please help me..

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for scroll to top.? Generally setting the scroll to top works with calculating the size of status bar and navigation bar so I say you need take the size of those elements in to account. Post your code please.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey,nothing to do new for scroll to top,my tableView scrolling up and down automatically..

Comment: one more thing, you can set the content offset of the tableview manually. that way it will override it. something like this [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES]; and set to where you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

In ios7,don’t set directly add 'tableHeaderView' as 'UISearchBar'.Firstly i added my 'UISearchBar' to plain 'UIView',then set my 'tableHeaderView' as plain 'UIView'.

```
by programatically do following code..

[self.plainView addSubview:mySearchBar];

self.mTableView.tableHeaderView = self.plainView
```